# Use Navigator.push (MaterialPageRoute) in a class method

Tags: flutter, dart, materialpageroute

I'm building an app using Flutter to play music.

I created a Class called MusicService with all the music functionalities implemented in methods like playMusic, seekMusic, onAudioComplete and so on.

I have my TrackScreen that is built based on the track (with the background of the track, the description and so on). In the init method of the screen I call an istance of MusicService to play music on the screen. So far so good.

What I would like to do is to build a new screen when a track is completed. This screen should be based on the next track in the playlist. 
The solution that I thougth is to call Navigator.Push in the onAudioComplete method of the class MusicService. The problem is that Navigator.Push requires a context and I don't know how specify it to refer to the context where it is called, i.e. the TrackScreen context.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem? Am I misunderstanding something?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate without `context` by using the `navigatorKey` of your `MaterialApp`

First, you have to declare a GlobalKey

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

and use it in your MaterialApp widget

```
child: MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: navKey,
  ...
```

After you will be able to get it to push new screens

```
navKey.currentState.push(...)
```